# Uncaught Error: Tabledit only works when applied to a table

Tags: javascript, php, tabledit

I have a table that is being populated correctly from a database, however, when i try to make any edits the following error is being reported back to me which prevents me from completing the edit to the column.

```
jquery.tabledit.js:22 Uncaught Error: Tabledit only works when applied to a table.
```

I would like to edit the values in the **choice** column, and I would be grateful if you would please look over my code and let me know where I may have gone wrong with this.

```html
<?php
//StaffArea

/** Include the mysql connection */
require 'includes/connect.php';

$stmt = $conn->prepare(" SELECT * FROM `students` WHERE `choice` = 'NOSPORT' ");

$stmt->execute();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
 <title>Untitled Document</title>
 <!-- Bootstrap -->
 <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="jquery-tabledit/jquery.tabledit.js"></script>
 <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $('#nstable').Tabledit({
   url: 'example.php',
   columns: {
    identifier: [0, 'id'],
    editable: [6, 'choice']
   },
   onDraw: function () {
    console.log('onDraw()');
   },
   onSuccess: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    console.log('onSuccess(data, textStatus, jqXHR)');
    console.log(data);
    console.log(textStatus);
    console.log(jqXHR);
   },
   onFail: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log('onFail(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)');
    console.log(jqXHR);
    console.log(textStatus);
    console.log(errorThrown);
   },
   onAlways: function () {
    console.log('onAlways()');
   },
   onAjax: function (action, serialize) {
    console.log('onAjax(action, serialize)');
    console.log(action);
    console.log(serialize);
   }
  });
 </script>  
 <style>

   .table.user-select-none {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
   }

 </style>
  </head>

  <body>
 <div class="container"></div>
 <table class="table" id="nstable" style="border:1px solid red">
   <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>Username</th>
    <th>StudentID</th>
    <th>Year</th>
    <th>Choice</th>
  </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
<?php while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { ?>
   <tr>
     <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['firstname']; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['lastname']; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['username']; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['studentid']; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['year']; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['choice']; ?></td>
   </tr>
<?php } ?>
   </tbody>
 </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I may have jumped the gun with my answer, can you show your code that is located in **example.php**.

Comment: <?php
//StaffArea

/** Include the mysql connection */
require 'includes/connect.php';
 
$input = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST);
 
if ($input['action'] === 'edit') 
{   
 
 $stmt = $conn->prepare(" UPDATE `students` SET `choice`= '" . $input['choice'] . "' WHERE id='" . $input['id'] . "' ");

 $stmt->execute();
 
} 
 
echo json_encode($input);
?>

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.

It looks like you are trying to use table edit on a file when what you want to be doing is is using it directly on the table. This is how it should be used.

```
$('#my-table').Tabledit({
    columns: {
      identifier: [0, 'id'],                   
      editable: [[1, 'First Name'], [2, 'Last Name']]
}
```

The Ajax part of the code is used after the edits have been "saved". bind a listener to a button and in the listener you will need to keep track of all the fields edited and when the listener finds changes that need sending, that is when you make the ajax call with the altered data.

Comment: Thanks Chris, very much appreciate your help, however, it is still giving me errors.  Also, that was taken directly from the Tabledit example:  https://markcell.github.io/jquery-tabledit/#examples

Comment: ps also getting                                                                                             
 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at showNeg.js:241
    at XMLHttpRequest.onDefaultReadyStateChangeHandler

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem is to run the script after the table.  This lets the full table be generated before the jquery runs.

Answer (score -1):

first you check to data execute

print

```
var_dump($stmt->fetch_assoc());
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your comment, the table is being generated correctly from data in the database, which leads me to believe that  <?php while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))  this code snippet is doing what it is meant to.